# When I pressed command+s to save in xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra

When I pressed command+s to save, the small selection window will appears in sometimes. How I can disable this?

[image]

I'm using xcode 8.3.3 on Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popover appears after a certain delay to have convenient access to diacritics and special characters associated to that key.

The simple solution is to (get used to) release the <kbd>s</kbd> key quickly.

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your comment. I will release the key quickly. thank you.